# why VT-x support is disabled

Tags: windows-8.1

I have an intel core i5-3470 processor which seems to support vt-x 
http://ark.intel.com/ru/products/68316/Intel-Core-i5-3470-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz

My motherboard asus p8z77 also seems to support vt-x. Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. But different software like SecurAble or VirtualBox report that my system does not support VT-x. What might be wrong?

My OS is Windows 8.1. Probably something is wrong with it.

Comment: Do you have any virtualization software installed? When VT-x is in use, it's not available because nested virtualization is not supported.

Comment: The only suspect is Windows Phone SDK that comes with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I have found a solution. The problem was with Hyper-v which was installed by windows phone sdk. After removing hyper-v checks in "windows add/remove components" everything turned ok.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is brilliant. Most threads online talk about enabling it in BIOS, but on my machine VirtualBox just stopped working. Even CPU-Z said that my **i7 doesn't support VT-x**. Turns out Hyper-V was installed by a VS Update (I believe VS 2015 Update 2, but not sure). Not sure if there is a way to fix the issue without uinstalling Hyper-V, but you should certainly mark this as the answer.